# how can I use order and between in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, between

i have a problem using Order and Between in this mysql code:

```
<?php 

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$id = $_GET["id"];
$query = "Select * from my_data where id between ($id+1) and ($id+4)";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $array[] = $row;    
}
header('Content-Type:Application/json');
echo json_encode($array);?>
```

i want the output in descending order by id 
please help me

Comment: First of all, visit http://bobby-tables.com to learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them. For the order thing: `ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: `Select * from my_data where id between ($id+1) and ($id+4) ORDER BY id DESC` - You can change also from DESC to ASC

Answer (score 0):

So you want the entry with the highest id first? Then it should be like this:

```
Select * from my_data where id between ($id+1) and ($id+4) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

$query = "Select * from my_data where id between ($id+1) and ($id+4) order by id desc";

Beware of SQL injection with the way you are handling your queries!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$id = $_GET["id"];
$query ="";
$query.= "Select * from my_data where id between ($id+1) and ($id+4)";
$query.= " order by id DESC"; //concat query as per requirement. 
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $array[] = $row;    
}
header('Content-Type:Application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

you can also pass order by field name and order by type(asc/desc) dynamically by setting them on variable. 
feel free to ask any query regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's Try this :

> I have added an  extra `order` parameter if it is not set then it will give descending order other wise set it to `&order=asc` for acceding order result. ordering is performed on `id` in field.

**Update your database connection setting**

```
<?php 

   //kindly change connection parameter as per you need
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
   $id = $_GET["id"];

   isset( $_GET['order']) ? $order =$_GET['order'] : $order= 'desc';

   if($order === 'asc'){
       $query = "Select * from person where id between ($id+1) and ($id+4) order by id asc";
   }else{
       $query = "Select * from person where id between ($id+1) and ($id+4) order by id desc";
   }


  $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;    
 }
 header('Content-Type:Application/json');

    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

**NOTE THE URL **

**OUTPUT ASC**
[image]

**Output DESC**
[image]